# Add "link only answer" to a flag description

Tags: feature-request, flags, link-only-answers

I know that there is some amount of debate on how to judge whether or not an Answer qualifies as a "link only answer" but avoiding that discussion entirely, could we get the reason added to the list of possible issues to raise a "Not an Answer" (or "low quality") flag for?

---

### Not an Answer -

#### Current state:

> **It is not an answer:**
>   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

#### Proposed text:

> **It is not an answer:**
>   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question or only supplies a link without adequate supporting information. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

---

### Low Quality

An alternative suggestion would be to add to the "Low quality" flag:

#### Current state:

> **It is very low quality**
>   This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

#### Proposed text:

> **It is very low quality**
>   This answer has severe formatting or content problems or just supplies a link without adequate supporting information. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

---

I would disagree with the second option as while, at face value, calling the Answer "Low quality" seems a better fit, the description suggests that the flag should be used when editing would likely not save the post which in the case of "link only answers" would not really fit as it would be quite straight forward to add in the expected example, explanation or other information.

Comment: It's also not really "not an answer".. it may well be a good answer... just not fitting our preferences regarding including the details in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think that everyone can agree that it is not an answer that meets the quality guidelines for the site. I'm hoping to get rid of some of the ambiguity relating to how to address such a post. Whether or not a specific post fits the requirements for "link only" will always be subjective to a degree but how to respond to one shouldn't be.

Comment: Given that one of the options in the low-quality queue is "link only answer" I'd be more inclined to go that route. Though perhaps the flag for low-quality could also auto-comment something about improving the answer...

Comment: The "First Posts" and "Late Answers" queues could benefit from a similar option. Firsts Posts especially suffer from these types of posts.